# Single SQL query that finds out details of users who have visited ‘pricing’ + 1 other page, and have a session time > 45 seconds

Tags: sql-query-store

I have to assume the database table and then find out the details of users who have visited other pages and have session time > 45 seconds.

Table contains: (visitor_id, session_id, session_start, session_end, page_visited).

session_start and session_end have format  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.
page_visited has the pages visited by that user in that session.